# Q: How do I write file.CSV in tcl/tk scripting

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, tcltk

I have 3 strings: `string1 string2 string3`

I want to export file.csv

I try to use

```
echo "string1,string2,string3" >> file.csv
```

but its not working

Comment: Why are you using shell code, if you want to write a Tcl program? Also, you need to clarify: Do you have literal strings, or Tcl variables holding those strings?

Answer (score 0):

File handling in Tcl takes a few more commands (but is more efficient when you're writing many lines as a result):

```
set f [open file.csv w]
puts $f "string1,string2,string3"
close $f
```

The `w` is critical: it says to open the file for ***w***riting.

---

If you're doing a lot of CSV writing, use the package in Tcllib for the job. It handles complicated edge cases for you.